# IMAP library : get all emails from outlook email account with lumen

Tags: php, laravel, outlook, imap, lumen

I am using below library ,

```
"php-imap/php-imap": "^3.0"
```

I want to get all the emails from email account , I am using below method,

```
 $mailboxs = new \PhpImap\Mailbox('{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl}',
                        "outlook_email_account",
                        "outlook_email_password",
                        "attachment"
                    );
 $mailsIds = $mailboxs->searchMailbox('ALL');
```

It gives me few mails ids , I want to get all ids of all emails of outlook account.Is it possible.I also want to know the mailbox name of emails.

Please can you tell me which method I can use to get all emails

Comment: Not sure why, however, please make sure .. does outlook provide the ability to get all. or you can try with gmail to make sure. May be limitations.

Comment: IMAP only allows you to search one folder at a time.  If you want all folders, you will have to LIST the folders, and cycle through them all yourself.